# Aptana crashes on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: macos, aptana3

Aptana studio used to work fine on OS X El Capitan but after updating to Sierra it doesn't work anymore... Can anybody help me fix this? I keep getting a crash log every time [screenshot uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8U6F.jpg) I open the app. Something I've noticed is that the aptana icon in the applications is a folder and not just a normal app icon. Earlier as I remember it was just a normal app icon on El Capitan. I use aptana on a daily basis as a university student so its vital for me for this to work.

Edit: I have tried a lot of methods including reinstalling java but still it doesn't work. Only way to make it work is to open up the application package and open the terminal executable aptana3. It runs perfectly then but if I launch from the usual app drawer icon it crashes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This security measure can correct it from **System Preferences -> Security and Privacy** -> General tab.

By default, Sierra, the option “Allow applications downloaded from does not appear **Anywhere** “. But with a simple instruction from the command line so we can correct.

1. Go to the folder **Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal**
2. In Terminal, enter or copy…

**sudo spctl --master-disable**

3. Type your password (it will not appear, however it is present) and press **Enter**

Click the lock and enter your Administrator password to make changes.

After changing this option, and can install any software, so if compatible with OS 10.12.

Comment: I ran that command. Restarted and still the same error though.. :(

Comment: Do I have to change anything in the aptana.ini file?

Comment: Sorry, I updated edit... Open System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> General tab e please, you choose option **Anywhere**.

Comment: Forget about aptana.imi, not java, nothing... You try **sudo spctl --master-disable** and you choose **Anywhere**.

Comment: Guys after doing this delete aptana, REBOOT and then reinstall! It works fine now thanks again!

Comment: Ahahahahah I glad

Comment: Do you have any issue with the text cursor on aptana? It seems to disappear after some time and I have trouble finding it again. Let me know if you know how to fix this...

Answer (score 9):

1. Open finder and navigate to "Applications -> Aptana"
2. Right click on the Aptana executable and click show contents
3. Navigate to "Content -> MacOS"
4. Double click click on AptanaStudio3
5. You will get a popup saying you need legacy Java SE 6
6. Click "More Info..." button and download and install it (very slow download, just wait it out)
7. Once installed double click the AptanaStudio icon in step 4 and Aptana Studio 3 will open
8. You will need to use that as the shortcut as the Aptana icon from installation will still not work.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem and solved with some workaround.

First download and install java for mac: https://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1572/en_US/javaforosx.dmg

If this not work or you reinstalled aptana after upgrading to sierra I advice to find a old copy of aptana directory and put it to application directory.

Comment: I have tried everything now and finally found something. If i right click the app and click check contents, Then open up macOS folder and then click aptanastudio3 executable a terminal window opens and it runs properly! Is there a way to get that to the main icon to run?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems on MacOS Sierra; crashing on load, or the JVM error if I launch from within the package contents.

I didn't find any solution to this directly, but instead I installed the latest version of Eclipse first, then installed Aptana from Eclipse. That seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Aptan on El Capitan, first you must install the legacy `java 6` version for `mac`:

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

The only thing is that you won't be able to access it like a normal application on your mac.

To open `Aptana` you must run:

```
Applications -> Aptana(right click to "Show package contents") -> Contents -> MacOS -> AptanaStudio3
```